# Onmouseover IE issues

Tags: internet-explorer, onmouseover

I'm making a website for a work friend free of charge, obviously I have limited knowledge and experience which is why I'm here asking for help.

I'm not sure if I need a .js file or .css file to make the onmouseover work; I'm completely out of ideas now.

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>

    <head>
        <!-- CHANGE THE NEXT THREE LINES -->
        <title>Parkley Visual Arts</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Parkley Visual Arts. Graphic Design & Art">
        <meta name="KeyWords" content="Graphic Design, Graphic Arts, Frame Pictures, Frame Pics, Photopgraphy, Leamington Arts, Leamington Graphics, Leamington Designs, Warwickshire Graphic Arts">
        <!-- CHANGE THE ABOVE THREE LINES -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <META name="Copyright" content="Copyright 2013 Parkley Visual Arts">
        <META http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
        <META name="revisit-after" content="15 days">
        <META name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <META name="Rating" content="General">
        <META name="Robots" content="All">
        <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
        <link rel=StyleSheet href="corporatestyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="javascripts.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="pop-closeup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                "use strict";
                var Minilogo, Eyewinker, LearnMore;
                Minilogo = document.getElementById('Minilogo');
                Eyewinker = document.getElementById('Eyewinker');

                Minilogo.onmouseover = function() {
                    Minilogo.src = 'Minilogo.gif';
                };
                Eyewinker.onmouseover = function() {
                    TW.src = 'Eyewinker.gif';
                };

                Minilogo.onmouseout = function() {
                    Minilogo.src = 'Minilogo.gif';
                };
                Eyewinker.onmouseout = function() {
                    Eyewinker.src = 'Eyewinker.gif';
                };
            };

            if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                countryListItem.attachEvent('onmouseover', sp.showPanel('item' + x), false);
            } else {
                countryListItem.addEventListener('mouseover', sp.showPanel('item' + x), false);
            }

            function swapImage(imgID, imgSrc) {
                var theImage = document.getElementById(imgID)
                theImage.src = imgSrc;
            }

            function preLoadImages() {
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                    var tmpImage = new Image();
                    tmpImage.src = arguments[i];
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="preLoadImages('Eyewinker.gif');">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <center><a href="http://www.parkleyvisualarts.com/construction.htm"><img id="imgToSwap" src="Minilogo.gif" alt="animated gif" onmouseover="swapImage('imgToSwap', 'Eyewinker.gif')" onmouseout="swapImage('imgToSwap', 'Minilogo.gif')" /></a>

        </div>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: I'm sure it took a lot of time to wrap each line of code in backticks, but please undo that and use four spaces in front of the lines instead. You can also paste the code to the question, highlight it and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: lol it sure did, did I change it correctly? thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to this, you should probably try to avoid verbose JavaScript, as it will be rather difficult for you to manage. Instead, I would encourage you to start with image attributes like `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` instead. Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hover-Fading Buttons</title>
        <base href="http://parkleyvisualarts.com/" />
        <style>
            img.logo {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="Minilogo.gif" class="logo"
             onmouseover=" this.src = 'Eyewinker.gif' " 
             onmouseout=" this.src = 'Minilogo.gif' " />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cannot thank you enough! you sir, are a very kind legend! completely fixed it for me! I added "border: 0; " so there was no box around the image in IE but many many thanks! Made my day :)